# Counting how many times a value appeared

Tags: sql, counting

I am using `SELECT DISTINCT  name FROM table` to get a table with distinct names that appear in the column. How can i get an extra column returning the number of times that this specific name have appeared on the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select name, count(1) from table
group by name;
```