# Counting how many times rows appear in one table in Access

Tags: sql, count, subquery, ms-access-2003

I'd like to show how many times a name appears in a field in an Access 2003 table. here's the table structure and content:

I used this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437619/counting-how-many-times-a-value-appeared):

Tabel:

```
     1  - Name1   
     1  - Name2
     2  - Name1
     2  - Name3
     3  - Name1
     3  - Name2
```

Result

```
    Name1 - 3
    Name2 - 2
    Name3 - 1
```

Here is the code i have

```
SELECT DISTINCT [tbl funktietitels].persoon, 

           [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode, [tbl funktietitels].funktietitel, [tbl funktietitels].userID, [tbl funktietitels].adres, [tbl funktietitels].dept, EXISTS
           (
               SELECT  [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode, COUNT([tbl funktietitels].funktiecode)
               FROM    [tbl funktietitels] 
               GROUP BY [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode 
           ) AS 'AMOUNT'
FROM ([tbl goedkeuring]

          INNER JOIN [tbl funktietitels] ON [tbl goedkeuring].goedk1 = [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode) 
          INNER JOIN [tbl doc] ON [tbl goedkeuring].volgnummer = [tbl doc].goedID


WHERE ((([tbl goedkeuring].bevestiging)=False));
```

This is what displays as the result:

```
  persoon   funktiecode   funktietitel     userID   adres   dept    'AMOUNT'
Name, Name2 DLB          King of the sea       JGO            LOG      �
```

How do I count how many times a field appears in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [tbl funktietitels].persoon, 
           [tbl goedkeuring].goedk1, 
           [tbl goedkeuring].db_user

             (SELECT  count(*)
              FROM  [tbl goedkeuring]
              WHERE [tbl goedkeuring].goedk1 = [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode
                     AND ((([tbl goedkeuring].bevestiging)=False))
             ) AS aantal

  FROM [tbl goedkeuring] 
       INNER JOIN [tbl funktietitels] 
           ON [tbl goedkeuring].goedk1 = [tbl funktietitels].funktiecode;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a count where the code is the same as the main table. This example aliases `[tbl funktietitels]` as t and as f.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.persoon, 
          f.funktiecode, 
          f.funktietitel, 
          f.userID, 
          f.adres, 
          f.dept, 
           (
               SELECT  COUNT(t.funktiecode)
               FROM    [tbl funktietitels] t
               WHERE   t.funktiecode = f.funktiecode
           ) AS 'AMOUNT'
       FROM ([tbl goedkeuring]
       INNER JOIN [tbl funktietitels] f 
          ON [tbl goedkeuring].goedk1 = f.funktiecode) 
       INNER JOIN [tbl doc] 
          ON [tbl goedkeuring].volgnummer = [tbl doc].goedID
       WHERE ((([tbl goedkeuring].bevestiging)=False));
```